# Moshe Rabbeinu's actions - why did he flee the serpent in Shemot 4:3?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu

In Shemoth 4:3, it says:

And He said, "Cast it to the ground," and he cast it to the ground, and it became a serpent, and Moses fled from before it.     וַיֹּ֨אמֶר֙ הַשְׁלִיכֵ֣הוּ אַ֔רְצָה וַיַּשְׁלִכֵ֥הוּ אַ֖רְצָה וַיְהִ֣י לְנָחָ֑שׁ וַיָּ֥נָס משֶׁ֖ה מִפָּנָֽיו:‏

Why did Moshe Rabbeinu have to flee from before the serpent?

If you are standing in front of G_d himself, even if you get bitten by the snake and die right there, wouldn't it be normal to think that G_d will bring you back to life ASAP?

We are dealing with someone who obviously had a ton of faith in Ha-Shem.

Comment: We all have human reactions, even Moshe Rabeinu.

Comment: @GershonGold it's a good question - a strong reading of the mitzva of emunat Hashem would preclude a person from being afraid of such matters, which is hard to picture with Moshe.

Answer (score 1):

[Ramban states](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=he) Moshe ran away because **he feared *Hashem***, not the snake - **he believed Hashem might punish him through the snake**.

Why did he fear this?

He new that he had committed a sin of slandering the Jewish people, something Hashem takes very seriously! [He said](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> "maybe they won't believe me"

which sounds harmless (Hashem literally said a [few pasukim later](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "and if they don't believe you..."), but [Hashem describes](https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.2.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) touching the Jewish people like touching the pupil of one's eye, l'mashal, even a slight *touch* of someone's eye hurts. Don't speak badly about My kids (although I am allowed to)!

Comment: "_Ramban states Moshe ran away because he feared Hashem, not the snake - he believed Hashem might punish him through the snake._" If he really believed Hashem might punish him through the snake, what good would running away do him?

Comment: @TamirEvan Buy him a few more seconds to do mitzvot? btw, is there any value in not being afraid of _definite_ punishment?

Comment: "_btw, is there any value in not being afraid of definite punishment?_" [Mesilat Yesharim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mesilat_Yesharim.24.4-5?lang=bi&lang2=en) says that fear of punishment is befitting only for the ignorant and the light-minded women, but not for sages and men of knowledge. (By the way, I wasn't asking about Moshe _being afraid_ of the punishment through the snake, but about him _running away_ from it.)

Comment: @TamirEvan let me rephrase: is there any value in someone recoiling with a fear response to imminent pain/death, even if it's from Hashem? This MY is talking about people who only serve Hashem because they fear the punishment of not doing so. Honestly asking, I don't know and would like to!

Comment: "_is there any value in someone recoiling with a fear response to imminent pain/death, even if it's from Hashem?_" In general, yes: one's natural sense of self preservation. The problem is that shouldn't be a factor if we assume Moshe had Emunat Hashem that would preclude him from being afraid of such matters. Personally, I'm with [Gershon Gold](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132948/moshe-rabbeinus-actions-why-did-he-flee-the-serpent-in-shemot-43/132950?noredirect=1#comment440636_132948) on this one.

Comment: Also, Ramban actually says [there](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.4.3?lang=bi&p2=Ramban_on_Exodus.4.3.1&lang2=bi): "וזה טעם וינס משה מפניו, כי פחד שמא יענש וינשכו הנחש **וכל אדם מתרחק מן המזיק לו אע''פ שידע** שאם יהיה כן בחפץ השם אין מציל מידו" ("And this is the sense of the expression, and Moses fled from before it [the serpent]. He feared lest he would be punished and the serpent would bite him, **since every person naturally avoids danger, even though Moses knew** that if it was indeed G-d’s desire [to punish him], there was no one that could deliver him out of His hand.").

Answer (score 0):

The serpent represents many thing's, if you look at the hieroglyphs you will see the serpent on pharos head. The answer is mainly from Kabbala, the mystical realm of the mind in connection to the world.

I am not a professional, nor a Kabbalist, just one that prays.

From what I know, (articles, and such) the serpent is based from the kundalini, (the lower bone of the spine) Thats why we have to bow in tefila and make our spine like the snake (Gemara Kedushin daf lamed) if not you won't be resurrected when mashiach comes. The story with the seven headed serpent in the bait-midrash.

This being so, g_d works in secret ways, like a serpent he does not know what color is, nor what animals are, he just sees energy (Thats why he asks Adam ha rishon, "What do you see")

Again this is all connected with Energy and Mind manipulation, the alfa snake is one you must be careful as they can bite you and you will never recover, like the bite of the wise men.

you can also see a connection with a big Kabbalist, rabbi Abraham Abulafia, and three headed serpent that represents, christianity, judaism and islam. The three main (alfa) religions in the world, irrelevant of the size of the religion.

There's a story of Rabbi Zalman mutsafi Another great Kabbalist of the twentieth century, he was praying for the holocaust to stop, (along with rabbi ptaya, though they were not together, and rabbi ptaya did more things). during his prayer he was shown a serpent with metal fangs, and voice from behind the serpent said, him, "I recommend you to stop, no one can defeat this serpent, as a bite from this you won't recover)  from then on, rabbi mutsafi stoped praying in relation to.

We see from here that Moshe was not afraid of the serpent only the hidden message it portrayed, that he was talking to a real diety, remember nowhere does it say that Moshe knew hashem before like he knew hime after, so you can presume, that his first encounter was that of an alien encounter, and not a mere mortal mind that he himself could defeat, once he saw this, he knew right away, he was talking with the real serpent, or dragon, teli.